# Sorting structs based on multiple conditions?

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda

So basically, I'm trying to sort a vector of `struct Entry` (each `Entry` has a `string word` and an `int count`) by the values of the `int`s. I managed to do that via an inline lambda expression:

```
vector<Entry*> entries(old); //make copy of old vector
std::stable_sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(), [] (const Entry *lhs,   const Entry *rhs){
    return (lhs->count > rhs->count);
});
```

However, the problem I have now is, if two or more `Entry`s have the same `count`, I need to sort those in alphabetical order. Is it possible to use another lambda expression somewhere in there, or is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The duplicate question is a bit older and missed C++11 answers, but that's now fixed. Do feel free to upvote my new answer there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple:

```
std::stable_sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(),
 [] (const Entry *lhs,   const Entry *rhs)
 {
    if( lhs->count != rhs->count )
        return lhs->count > rhs->count;
    else
        return lhs->word > rhs->word;
 });
```